# How to refer to the name of an object in C#

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to refer to an object's name in C# to avoid copying useless code like

```
public static void Main (string[] Args)
{
     Champion aatrox = new Champion("Aatrox"); 
     Champion ahri   = new Champion("Ahri"); 
     // and so on ...
}
```

Been looking for something that looks like

```
class Champion 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }         
    public Champion () => Name = nameOf(this);
}
```

But didn't find any way to do so.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you want to achieve - where do you want to get the name from? nameof(this) would be "Champion" for each champion. You need to define the name at some kind of place, the framework cannot generate names.

Comment: I think I understand what you want - you want the name of the variable to be the name of the champion. Not a good idea, I'll write an answer ;)

Comment: From right to left: `new Champion(...)` creates a new instance, `=` assigns that instance to a variable declared as `Champion aatrox`. A variable "holding" (or referencing) an instance is (for reference types) not the same thing as the instance. What should the value of `Name` be if you say `Champion maseltov = aatrox;`? Also, the variable is `aatrox` (lower case) but the name you give it is `"Aatrox"`(upper case). How should that work?

Comment: -- or better yet: `List<Champion> champions = new List<Champion> { new Champion(...), new Champion(...) };` -- how should the `Name` be infered here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use the variable name inside your object-instance, that is not possible and also not a good idea. You can use an object instance in different places in your code where the variable could be named differently (or not named at all like Corak [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51458942/how-to-refer-to-the-name-of-an-object-in-c-sharp/51459044#comment89887487_51458942)), so there is no single name available, making it impossible to create consistent logic out of this.

It also creates a dependency between your program logic and strings presented to the user - this can cause many more issues, e.g. if your name needs to contain spaces, if you want to use lower or upper casing different than your coding conventions, if you want to translate the names into different languages.

So what you want to achieve is not possible for good reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Everything @CompuFreak said is correct, and you should probably mark his answer as accepted.

But, one thing you can do is this:

```
Champion Aatrox = new Champion (nameof(Aatrox));
```

That gives you the minor advantage that if you realize that you spelled Aatrox wrong (say it is supposed to have two "x"-es), you could rename the variable name, and that name would ripple into your code. I used "nameof" all the time, but I'm not sure I'd use it here.

But, as has been pointed out, the main reason you can't do what you describe is that the name you give a variable that references an object you create is not intrinsically known to the object; it's just a name you give to something that *references* the object (and many things can reference the same object). That reference name is only know in the *scope* where it's used.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this can be done with fields, but it can be done with properties using the CallerMemberNameAttribute:

```
class Champion {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Champion([CallerMemberName] string name = "") {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

This will pass the property name to the constructor. The folowing will print the expected names "Aatrox" and "Ahri":

```
class Program {
    static Champion Aatrox { get; set; } = new Champion();
    static Champion Ahri { get; set; } = new Champion();

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Console.WriteLine(Aatrox.Name);
        Console.WriteLine(Ahri.Name);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

If you are creating instances of the class in places you don't want to use properties you can wrap it in a class:

```
class ChampionContainer {
    public Champion Aatrox { get; set; } = new Champion();
    public Champion Ahri { get; set; } = new Champion();
}
```

And use it like this

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
        ChampionContainer champions = new ChampionContainer();
        Console.WriteLine(champions.Aatrox.Name);
        Console.WriteLine(champions.Ahri.Name);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```